# I can just conclude the bounty doesn't work for me

Tags: support

I will propose 50 reward on this question.

[Catch Javascript CustomEvent by jQuery on() preserving custom properties at first "level"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835724/catch-javascript-customevent-by-jquery-on-preserving-custom-properties-at-firs)

But I cant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot post a bounty on a question until it is at least 2 *days* old.  Your question is barely 2 *hours* old.

In ~45 hours, if you still want to post your bounty, you'll be able to.